# Not able to checkout code from git

Tags: git

I am trying to fetch source code from a repository but when I run command to fetch the source code I get an error which says "error pathspec did not match any files known to git".

Following is the sequence of command that i run to fetch source code.

```
$ git remote add origin git@....
$ git fetch
$ git checkout test
```

Comment: Usually, the error message is: `error: pathspec 'xxx' did not match any file(s) known to git`. Is there any data added after '`pathspec`' in your error message?

Comment: @VonC it says error pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git.

Comment: If you have that error on checkout, then janos' answer should be the correct one for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git tries to resolve `git checkout test` like this:

- If there is a local branch named "test", then checkout that
- If there is a remote branch named "test", for example `origin/test`, then create a local branch from it and checkout (equivalent to `git checkout -b test origin/test`
- If there is a file or directory named "test", then checkout that, which will undo uncommitted (but unstaged) changes to that file/directory

If none of the above match, then Git gives the error:

> error: pathspec 'test' did not match any file(s) known to git.

I'm not sure what you were trying to do here. If you wanted to checkout the "test" branch, it seems it doesn't exist. Check what branches you have with `git branch -a`. If you wanted to checkout a file/dir, it doesn't exist. Check what files you have with `git ls-files`.

Comment: Are you trying to checkout the "test" branch or a file or directory named "test"? If there is no "test" branch, you cannot checkout that. Why do you think there should be?

Comment: I am following some instructions to set up a test system on my local system. My peers have told me that there is a branch called "test". Also on console it displays "(master)" at the end of the destination folder.

Comment: @ janos Thanks for your help, there was a problem in connection with the repository. It seems to be working now.

Comment: Note: The lookup order is different - Git first looks for a local branch, then looks for local files, then looks for any remote branches. In my case I had a »test« directory and a »test« branch on a remote, which caused Git to always “checkout“ the file. Solution: Create a local branch based on a remote first `gib branch test origin/test`, then proceed with the checkout. Or use the short-form of this answer, `git checkout -b test origin/test`.

Comment: PS: Even shorter solution `git checkout test --`. Git uses the `--` to differ between branch and files, if no filename is given in the checkout command it will skip the local filename fallback.